# Logarithm size comparison

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

> Which of the following is less than log$_747$?
>
> a. $\ln e^2$
>
> b. log$_4418$
>
> c. log$_547$
>
> d. log$_{14}94$
>
> e. None of these.

Clearly, a,b,c are all equal to 2 or larger than 2. However, without a calculator (since I am not allowed to use a calculator for this problem), how can I know whether the answer is d or e?

Comment: Hint:  $94=2\times 47$.  $14=2 \times 7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compare:
$$\log_7 47 \ \ or \ \ \log_{14} 94.$$
Express both sides as power of $14$:
$$(2\cdot 7)^{\log_7 47} \ \ or \ \ 14^{\log_{14} 94} \iff $$
$$2^{\log_7 47}\cdot 47 \ \ or \ \  94 \iff$$
$$2^{\log_7 47} \ \ or \ \ 2^1 \iff$$
$$\log_7 47 \ \ or \ \ 1 \ \iff$$
$$47>7^1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a = \log_7 47$ and $b=\log_{14} 94$. Then $7^a = 47$ and $14^b=94$. Then $a>1$, so if $b\geq a$, then we have $7^b \geq 49$ and $2^b>2$, and consequently $94=14^b=2^b7^b>2\cdot 47>94$. This contradiction proves $b<a$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_{14}94=\frac{\ln 94}{\ln 14}=\frac{\ln 2+\ln 47}{\ln 2+\ln 7}<\frac{\ln 47}{\ln 7}$$